# Bring Class Leader Id on top of the list using Java8 Streams

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of students and I want to bring only the leaderId on top of the same list following remains the remaining list items using Java Streams. I tried the below logic but it is not working as expected

```
List<Student> students = ....

Long leaderId = 123;

students.stream().sort((s1,s2) -> leaderId.equals(s1.getId()) || leaderId.equals(s2.getId()) ? 1: 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can anyone please give me some suggestion on this

### Example

**List of students:**

```
[{id:121, name:"John"}, {id:131, name:"Susan"}, {id:123, name:"Jacob"}, {id:155, name:"Sunny"}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{id:123, name:"Jacob"}, {id:121, name:"John"}, {id:131, name:"Susan"}, {id:155, name:"Sunny"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own comparator first which places the leader at the front of the list when sorted using it. Then you have to use it for sorting the list. I don't see any point of using the streams here, since the iterative code looks more simple and readable. Here's how it looks in practice.

```
static class LeaderFirstComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    final long leaderId;

    LeaderFirstComparator(long leaderId) {
        this.leaderId = leaderId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        if (o1.id == leaderId && o2.id != leaderId)
            return -1;
        else if (o1.id != leaderId && o2.id == leaderId)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```

And the client code:

```
students.sort(new LeaderFirstComparator(leaderId));
```

**Update**

If the first object is the leader, then it should come before the second, hence returning -1 according to the contract. Otherwise, if the second object is the leader, then the first one should come after it, hence 1. If nether of the objects are the leader or both are leaders, then the original ordering is preserved. Thus returning 0.

As per the below comment, you can further simplify it to this one liner:

```
students.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getId() != leaderId));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please explain what does the -1, 1, 0 means under the context of matching the id with leaderId

Comment: Your comparator has a bug. If both `Student` objects have an id matching `leaderId`, the comparator must return zero. But note that `Boolean` is a comparable type (`false < true`), so you can simply use `students.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getId() != leaderId));` Generally, the `Comparator.comparing…` factories are preferable as they avoid such bugs.

Comment: Good catch, I have updated my answer. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it’s correct now. But using `Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getId() != leaderId)` still would be simpler.

Answer (score -1):

If the leader has a concrete id equals to 123, yo can get it using only a filter

```
List leaderStudents = students.stream().filter(s1 -> leaderId.equals(s1.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this retrieves only the leader into a list, actually what I want is to bring the leader item  to the front of the same list following remains the remaining list items

Comment: I have given one example show casing the use case